# Can't connect to SQL Query Tool of Postgres running in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have docker container running Postgres. I can access the database via container terminal. But When I tried to connect the database via SQL Query Tool such as dbeaver, I have multiple error saying: database not found / postgres role not found.

What's the issue in my docker-compose file that I am missing?
[image: Error][image: Main Config]

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  pg_superset_dev:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
```

dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:13.2

COPY runtime/ /
```

Comment: Try connecting with PgAdmin4 it lists all the databases.

Comment: @nPcomp PgAdmin4 also gave me the same error

Comment: if `docker ps` is showing the container running you can get into container with `docker exec -it your_container_id /bin/bash` and try to see if the the database exist.

Comment: Where are you creating the `reporting` database?